# Junit test of void method

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I'm testing a method with a void return type, with one parameter. I'm trying to get at least some code coverage. Here's a method I'm testing:

```
@Service
public class VaultService {

    private final ProductRepository repository;

    private final DatabaseService databaseService;

    public VaultService(
            @Autowired BuildProperties buildProperties,
            ProductRepository repository,
            DatabaseService databaseService
    ) {
        logger.info("Creating service");

        this.repository = repository;
        this.databaseService = databaseService;
    }

    protected void checkVaultResponseErrors(VaultResponse vaultResponse) {
        if (vaultResponse.responseStatus != ResponseStatus.SUCCESS) {
            vaultResponse.errors.forEach(error -> {
                if (vaultResponse.responseStatus.equals(ResponseStatus.EXCEPTION)) {
                    throw new VaultException(error.getMessage());
                }
                if (vaultResponse.responseStatus.equals(ResponseStatus.FAILURE)) {
                    throw new VaultFailure(error.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

The VaultResponse class looks like this

```
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class VaultResponse {
    @JsonProperty("responseStatus")
    public ResponseStatus responseStatus;

    @JsonProperty("errors")
    public List<Error> errors;
}
```

And here is my test. I'm getting an error with the `Mockito.verify`, but the rest of the code also doesn't get any coverage. I obviously doing something wrong.

```
@Test
void should_check_vaultResponse_for_errors() {
    VaultService spyService = Mockito.spy(vaultService);
    VaultResponse vaultResponse = new VaultResponse();
    ResponseStatus status = ResponseStatus.SUCCESS;
    List<Error> error = new ArrayList<>();

    vaultResponse.setResponseStatus(status);
    vaultResponse.setErrors(error);

    doThrow(IllegalArgumentException.class)
            .when(spyService).checkVaultResponseErrors(vaultResponse);
    doNothing().when(spyService).checkVaultResponseErrors(vaultResponse);

    verify(spyService, times(1)).checkVaultResponseErrors(vaultResponse);
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? It seems to me you are not calling `checkVaultResponseErrors` during the test

Comment: It seems you're right. I'm getting `Wanted but not invoked:
vaultService.checkVaultResponseErrors. Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.`

Comment: you have to call somehow (you will not be able to call protected methods from the test, so you'll have to make it public) that method between the doNothing and the verify

Comment: keep in mind also that probably doThrow and doNothing in your case are incompatible, since you are telling mockito to throw an exception when the method is invoked, and at the same time to do nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test method clearly indicates that you want to test the `checkVaultResponseErrors` method. That means you should most definitely *not* mock it. You can mock anything needed to make it work, but not the method itself.

The way I see it, there are three tests to write:

1. No errors:

```
// create VaultResponse without errors; you have that now

assertDoesNotThrow(() -> vaultService.checkVaultResponseErrors(vaultResponse));
```

2. With an exception:

```
// create VaultResponse with status EXCEPTION

VaultException thrown = assertThrows(VaultException.class,
        () -> vaultService.checkVaultResponseErrors(vaultResponse));
// you can now assert that thrown is what you expect
```

3. With a failure:

```
// create VaultResponse with status FAILURE

VaultFailure thrown = assertThrows(VaultFailure.class,
        () -> vaultService.checkVaultResponseErrors(vaultResponse));
// you can now assert that thrown is what you expect
```